# last-child not working within my blockquote

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add closing quotation marks only to the last paragraph of blockquotes.

My CSS code is as following:

```
blockquote p:last-child:after{
    content: close-quote;
}
```

And my HTML is:

```
<blockquote>
<p>Travel is fatal to prejudice, bigotry, and narrow-mindedness, and many of our people need it sorely on these accounts. Broad, wholesome, charitable views of men and things cannot be acquired by vegetating in one little corner of the earth all one's lifetime.</p>
<p>Here is second paragraph</p>
</blockquote>
```

Somehow, this isn't working. I've  reviewed the specification of :last-child on w3schools, seems all correct.

Here is the actual web-page: http://www.aspenwebsites.com/lothlorien/layouts-typography/

Could you please advise on what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close-quote` can only be used when `open-quote` is also being used. For example, you would have to do:

```
blockquote p:last-child:before{
    content: open-quote;
}

blockquote p:last-child:after{
    content: close-quote;
}
```

If you absolutely want to force a closing quote, you can use:

```
blockquote p:last-child:after{
    content: "”";
}
```

However, on your website itself, you actually are using `open-quote` and it's the `:last-child` selector that's failing due to your `<blockquote>` having a `<footer>` tag as its last child (which isn't in the example you posted.) You should get around this by using the `:last-of-type` selector.

```
blockquote p:last-of-type:after{
    content: close-quote;
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9skwe1gr/)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the <footer> from the code sample above as I didn't think it mattered and to make code look less bulky. :) ... My bad. 

Thank you very much for clarifying the use of last-child for me. I thought it worked in exact same ways as last-of-type, and I wasn't aware of last-of-type all together.

Answer (score 1):

the code you've posted in the question is different from the code I can see in your webpage...

Actually it doesn't work because in your web-page the last-child in the `<blockquote>` is not a `<p>` at all (it is a `<footer>` element).

the `:last-child` selector targets to the last child element only and your rule `p:last-child` is ignored because in the `<blockquote>` element there's no last-child that is a `<p>` too.

If you don't want to change your html you should use this selectro instead:

```
blockquote p:last-of-type:after{content: close-quote;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. As it turns out I had a totally incorrect understanding of the last-child selector..